# When I use Binding.scala, I got the error `each instructions must be inside a SDE block`, how can I fix this?

Tags: scala, dom, data-binding, web-frontend, binding.scala

When I use Binding.scala, I want to create some `div`s according to source data `someCollection`:

```
val someCollection = Seq("foo", "bar")
someCollection.map { item =>
  <div>{item.bind}</div>
}
```

However, I got a compiler error `each instructions must be inside a SDE block`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I need someone help to create a `binding.scala` tag for this question. See https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/issues/47

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code that causes this error is that your `bind` expression must not be outside of the scope of the `@dom` macro. This can happen when creating a closure and can be resolved by:

1. Refactoring the code in the closure into its own `@dom` annotated method.
2. Converting `someCollection` to a `BindingSeq`, for example:

   `Constants(someCollection: _*).map { item => <div>{item.bind}</div> }`
3. Provide a `scalaz.Traverse` type class for the collection ([Run this example on ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/EHdex4U/2))

---

TL;DR

```
@dom def renderList(data: List[Binding[String]]) = <ol>{
  import scalaz.std.list._ // Type classes for List
  for (b <- data) yield {
    <li>{b.bind}</li>
  }
}</ol>
```