# How to render json result from api request using Binding.scala

Tags: scala, scala.js, binding.scala

I tried the following code to render json into dom but failed

```
       <div class="row">
        {val result = FutureBinding(ApiHomeProjectsGet.request())
      result.bind match {
        case None => <div>Loading...</div>
        case Some(Success(ApiHomeProjectsGetResponse200(projects))) =>     {
          for (project <- projects.items) yield <p> {project.title} </p>
        }
        case e => <div>Error</div>
      }}
      </div>
```

projects is defined as a case class

```
case class Projects(items: ArrayBuffer[Project])
```

the compiler reports error:

```
overloaded method value domBindingSeq with alternatives:
[error]   (text: String)com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.Constants[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Text] <and>
[error]   (node: org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node)com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.Constants[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node] <and>
[error]   (seq: Seq[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node])com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.Constants[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node] <and>
[error]   (bindingSeq: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.BindingSeq[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node])com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.BindingSeq[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node]
[error]  cannot be applied to (Object)
[error]           <div class="row">
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
```

How can I render json data from api request to dom with the for(...) yield pattern?

---

The best solution

```
     case Some(Success(ApiHomeProjectsGetResponse200(projects))) =>
        <div class="row">
          {Constants[Project](projects.items:_*).map(item => <p> {item.title} </p>)}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition of `Projects`, `projects.items` is of type `ArrayBuffer[Project]`. Your for comprehension desugars to `map`, the result is therefore of type `ArrayBuffer[dom.raw.Node]`.

In your pattern matching expression you are mixing `dom.raw.Node` and `ArrayBuffer[dom.raw.Node]`, the least upper bound of these two types is `Object` which is why it pops up in the error message.

One way to solve this problem would be to return a `dom.raw.Node` in every branch of the pattern matching, for example:

```
case ... =>
  <div>
    (for (project <- projects.items) yield <p> {project.title} </p>).toSeq
  </div>
```

Comment: I try to use the following code `            case Some(Success(ApiHomeProjectsGetResponse200(projects))) =>
              <div>
              (for (project <- projects.items) yield <p>{project.title}</p>).toSeq
              </div>`

Comment: but still get errors:

  in XML literal: name expected, but char '-' cannot start a name
  [error]               (for (project <- projects.items) yield <p>{project.title}</p>).toSeq

Answer (score 0):

For now, I can use a render function to solve this problem

```
          case Some(Success(ApiHomeProjectsGetResponse200(projects))) =>
          val projectsBinding = Vars[Project](projects.items:_*)
          <div>
             { renderProjectPanel(projectsBinding).bind}
          </div>

          @dom def renderProjectPanel(items: Vars[Project]) = {
              for (project <- items) yield <p>{project.title}</p>
          }
```

even though this needs to add some more code, but it works

Hope someone will give a simpler solution

Comment: `Vars` should be `Constants`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498968/when-i-use-binding-scala-i-got-the-error-each-instructions-must-be-inside-a-sd